# what is a cached string?

Tags: java, c, string, java-native-interface

What is a *cached String* ? or What is *caching of string* ? I have read this term several times in JNI but don't know what it is.

Comment: Maybe you should be a bit more specific... Caching is quite a common technique for performance purposes... Point out the docs you refer.

Comment: Read it where? Saying what about it?

Answer (score 1):

A [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) improves performance (which is important for JNI) and reduces memory usage.

Here is a simple String cache example, if you are interested how a simple caching algorithm could work - but this is really just an example and I don't suggest you should actually use it in your code:

```
public class StingCache {

    static final String[] STRING_CACHE = new String[1024];

    static String getCachedString(String s) {
        int index = s.hashCode() & (STRING_CACHE.length - 1);
        String cached = STRING_CACHE[index];
        if (s.equals(cached)) {
            return cached;
        } else {
            STRING_CACHE[index] = s;
            return s;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {

        String a = "x" + new Integer(1);
        System.out.println("a is: String@" + System.identityHashCode(a));

        String b = "x" + new Integer(1);
        System.out.println("b is: String@" + System.identityHashCode(b));

        String c = getCachedString(a);
        System.out.println("c is: String@" + System.identityHashCode(c));

        String d = getCachedString(b);
        System.out.println("d is: String@" + System.identityHashCode(d));

    }

}
```

Comment: I chose `Cache (Utah)` from your link. But didn't help :)

Comment: Hm, I originally got the German link and thought switching the language will do the trick. Obviously not... Fixed.

Comment: From what I read about JNI, caching of Strings is to improve performance - which would kind of make sense if you use JNI :-)

Comment: so what exactly is a cached string ? !

Comment: A cached string is a string in a cache. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sting.intern() already does exactly this. It remains unclear what exactly the OP is talking about.

Comment: @EJP String.intern() actually does a lot more. String.intern() is quite slow compared to simple caching (as above) but guarantees strings to be unique - something that is not very important in many cases.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Of course but if uniqueness isn't important you wouldn't use your string cache either.

Comment: @EJP you would still use a string cache if you care about performance (avoid to create new objects unnecessarily) and memory usage (avoid having lots of duplicates in memory)

Comment: @ThomasMueller In what way does either this code or `String.intern()` (a) help with avoiding creating new objects, or (b) fail to deal with 'having lots of duplicates in memory'?

Comment: @EJP My code is about how a simple caching mechanism looks like (how the code looks like). It does not help avoiding to create new objects, but it helps getting rid of duplicates (to free up memory). A cache in C (when using JNI) _would_ help avoiding to create new (Java) objects. I just didn't want to write C code. The Java code above can help reduce the memory usage of Java applications: a similar String cache is in use for example in the H2 database (String.intern isn't used for performance reasons).